# Как сделать отступы только у псевдокласа after

Tags: html, css

```
nav li {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a {       
text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:after {
content: "";
border-left: solid;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Хочу сделать полоски в меню, но когда даю отступы псевдокласу, то и меню тоже получает отступы.

Как сделать отступы только `before` или `after`?

Comment: Я, честно, пытался хотя бы понять о чём идёт речь...
Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно Вы имеете ввиду? И, наверное, главный вопрос - зачем? Псевдоэлементы, заметьте - не псевдоклассы, `::after` и `::before` для того и созданы, что-бы располагаться непосредственно после или до (соответственно) элементов, к которым они создаются.

Comment: так в чем разница между ::before и ::After от :before и :After

Comment: @СергейВасенин 
Псевдоэлемент **::before** применяется для отображения контента **до** содержимого элемента, к которому он добавляется
Псевдоэлемент,  **::after** используется для вывода контента **после** содержимого элемента, к которому он добавляется

https://webref.ru/css/after

Comment: я так понимаю вопрос касается количества двоеточий? При моем уровне знаний на данный момент - разницы нет. Разве что с уважения к старым браузерам ставят одно двоеточие, но это не точно.
В своем "ответе" я имел ввиду не кол-во двоеточий, а само название: это не псевдоклассы, это псевдоэлементы.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае вам нужно использовать абсолютное позиционирование


**Родителю добавить относительное позиционирование**

```
nav li{
    position: relative;
}
```

**А ребенку соответственно абсолютное позиционирование**

```
nav li:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-left: solid;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

В таком случае дочерний элемент не будет влиять на родителя!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так расположить псевдоэлементы

```css
nav li
    {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: .1em .4em;
    text-align: center;
    }

    nav li a
    {

                text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    top: 0;
    background: #000;
    width: 2px;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;


    }
```

```html
<nav>
<li>One</li>
<li>OneOneOne</li>
<li>One</li>
<li>OneOneOneOne</li>
</nav>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ но что будет правильней прописать в nav li border left solid 1px или через before

Answer (score -1):

Я немного по-другому решил вопрос: теперь не знаю, что будет правильней. В моём случае я прописал:

```
li {
  border-left:solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужна просто рамка слева, то border-left для этой задачи 100% лучшем чем псевдоэлемент before))) border-left: 1px solid red;